# How to fetch git-lab one specific branch to existing folder

Tags: git, gitlab

I need some help. I was trying to fetch one of my git-lab branch to local folder but it could not happen.I am explaining my command below.

```
subrajyoti@subrajyoti-H81M-S:/opt/lampp/htdocs/cargit/carClinic_correct$ git pull REMOTE challenge_d30_crypto_insecurerandomness_1 -u
```

But it gave me the following message.

```
fatal: 'REMOTE' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Here I need to fetch all code present inside that given branch. Please help.

Comment: you remote probably has a different name (`origin` maybe?). Please run `git remote` command to see the proper name of the remote.

Answer (score 0):

REMOTE must be a name or an URL of your remote repo; "origin" if you've configured it:

```
git pull origin …
```

or URL

```
git pull git@github.com/path/to/repo
```

And /path/to/repo must be real path.